# How to access javascript code from a controller in an Asp.Net Core MVC application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an Asp.Net Core MVC application that searches youtube videos and returns a list that is displayed on screen. Each video is placed in a custom component that has a checkbox. Every time a checkbox is selected I access a script that searches all the video components that are on the screen and I store the video id's in a list in my .cshtml page.

At some point I need to get this list of video id's to do a processing. For that I created a javascript method in the same .cshtml page to return this list of ids.
I've already done a research on JSRuntime on Blazor (.razor) pages but that wouldn't be my case.
The fact is that with the click of a button I need to call a controller method, and this method calls my javascript method which returns my list of ids.
How best to do this?

This my javascript code.

```js
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        var listaDeIds = [];
        function Mostrar() {
            //document.getElementById("btnplaylist").style.display = 'block';
            var videos = document.querySelectorAll('#video');
            var count = 0;
            var lista = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
                //console.log("1 -  " + videos.item(i).getAttribute("name"));
                var videoID = videos.item(i).getAttribute("name");
                //console.log("2 -  " + videos.item(i).getAttribute("id"));
                const shadow = videos.item(i).shadowRoot;
                const childNodes = Array.from(shadow.childNodes);
                //console.log("3 - " + childNodes.length);

                childNodes.forEach(childNode => {
                    if (childNode.nodeName === "DIV") {
                        //console.log("4 - " + childNode.nodeName);
                        const shadowChilds = Array.from(childNode.childNodes);
                        //console.log("5 - " + shadowChilds.length);
                        shadowChilds.forEach(shadowShild => {
                            if (shadowShild.nodeName === "DIV") {
                                //console.log("6 - " + shadowShild.nodeName);
                                const shadowChildsInternas = Array.from(shadowShild.childNodes);
                                //console.log("7 - " + shadowChildsInternas.length);
                                shadowChildsInternas.forEach(interna => {
                                    if (interna.nodeName === "INPUT") {
                                        //console.log("8 - Name " + interna.nodeName);
                                        if (interna.checked === true) {
                                            //console.log("9 - Checked: " + interna.checked);
                                            lista[count] = videoID;
                                            count = count + 1;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            if (lista.length > 0) {
                document.getElementById("btnplaylist").style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.getElementById("btnplaylist").style.display = 'none';
            }
            listaDeIds = lista;
        }

        function RetornaListaDeIds() {
            return listaDeIds;
        }
    </script>
```

This is my html component code

```html
<custom-iframe id="video" name="@item.Id.VideoId" urlvideo='@Url.Content(item.Url)' onclick="Mostrar()"></custom-iframe>
```

This is the button that calls my controller.

```html
<div id="btnplaylist" class="right_side hidden">
            <button value="Playlist" asp-controller="VideoSearch" asp-action="GravarSelecionados" class="btn green-button button-tamanho-padrao">Playlist</button>
        </div>
```

Code of my control.

[image]

Comment: Why not send the list of IDs directly to your controller via AJAX?

Comment: Can you provide a sample code?

Comment: You could also use the new JavaScript Fetch API: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_api_fetch.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing something at a high level here so bear with me.

Your use case is you want users to 'check' videos that you serve to them via a web app, visually altering the page elements around the videos and ultimately sending them off for processing, which I assume means some kind of storage or at least some back-end work.

If I understand your attempted solution to this problem correctly, it is impossible. Even if you did get your backend to run javascript, it wouldn't be aware of the client's state and could not read that list of videos off of it. There's no reason for javascript to run on your server as I see it.

Instead, you need your client-side Javascript to send that list of ids to your server via an API in a JSON format. The flow goes (user checks box -> JS on the browser collects the id of that video and formats a POST request with some json describing what was checked -> that JSON is sent to your server which then reads it an processes it)

The frontend javascript and the server should always communicate with eachother in this way. Again, there's no need for javascript to be run *on the server itself.*

Answer (score 0):

Moving on to thank everyone who gave suggestions for solving my problem for their support. I followed and tested all the suggestions and the one that fit best to my problem was the use of ajax, suggested by @Andre.Santarosa.

I followed the following article as a reference:http://www.macoratti.net/15/05/mvc_ajax.htm

I installed the package: Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
I added the script reference in my _Layout.cshtml:

```js
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

On the page that lists the videos, the code looks like this:

Button code:

```html
<div id="btnplaylist" class="right_side hidden">
            <input type="button" value="Playlist" id="Playlist" class="btn green-button button-tamanho-padrao" />
        </div>
```

Ajax Code:

```js
$('#Playlist').click(function () {
            var url = "/VideoSearch/PegarListaDeIds";
            var lista = listaDeIds;

            $.post(url, { pListaDeIds: lista }, function (data) {
                $("#msg").html(data);
            });
        });
```

[image: image result]